# Llamada de clases en Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Tengo una actividad llamada ServerGateway.dart y otra actividad llamada LoginEndpoint.dart dentro de LoginEndpoint.dart tengo creadas varios class entre ellos uno llamado LoginInterpreter el cual quiero llamarlo desde la actividad de ServerGateway.dart. El problema que estoy teniendo y que he probado es que llamo a la actividad LoginEndpoint.dart pero no me deja traerme el class LoginInterpreter.

Ejemplo:

Mismo paquete para las dos clases que pongo en ejemplo.

**ServerGateway.dart**

```
ServerGateway(TokensStorage tokensStorage) {
    this.tokensStorage = tokensStorage;
    // Esto es lo que he intentado, llamar a la Actividad.nombreClass pero me falla
    LoginEndpoint.LoginInterpreter loginInterpreter = new LoginEndpoint.LoginInterpreter(tokensStorage);
}
```

**LoginEndpoint.dart**

```
class LoginEndpoint {
 ...
}

class RequesterAction_ {
  ...
}

// Este es el class al que intento acceder desde la actividad ServerGateway.dart
class LoginInterpreter with ResponseInterpreter<TokensStorage>
{
    TokensStorage tokensStorage;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Puedes formular mejor tu pregunta y cuéntanos que has intentado y que error te produce

Comment: Tengo una actividad llamada **ServerGateway.dart** y otra actividad llamada **LoginEndpoint.dart** dentro de **LoginEndpoint.dart** tengo creadas varios **class** entre ellos uno llamado **LoginInterpreter** el cual quiero llamarlo desde la actividad de **ServerGateway.dart**. El problema que estoy teniendo y que he probado es que llamo a la actividad **LoginEndpoint.dart** pero no me deja traerme el class **LoginInterpreter**

Comment: puedes actualizar tu pregunta con todo eso que mencionas y en lo posible agregar tus clases o por lo menos las lineas iniciales

Comment: Lo voy a actualizar pero, el código no interfiere nada solo la llamada al **class** especificado anteriormente. De todas formas pongo un pequeño ejemplo para que se entienda mejor mi problema

Comment: @diegoveloper actualizado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto es incorrecto ya que no podemos declarar clases como estáticas.

```dart
LoginEndpoint.LoginInterpreter loginInterpreter
```

Lo que debes hacer es simplemente llamar a la clase directamente pero importar el archivo a donde pertenece.

```dart
//En la parte superior va el import a donde pertenece
import 'tu_directorio/LoginEndpoint.dart';


LoginInterpreter loginInterpreter = new LoginInterpreter(tokensStorage);
```

Además el IDE debería autocompletar ese import, si usas IntelliJ o VSCode.

Comment: Vale ya lo he entendido, pero también se podría hacer de otra manera ya que esa me seguía dando error. Lo que he echo es que en el **import** crear un prefix **as prefix** y se llama desde el prefix. Por ejemplo **loginEP.LoginInterpreter loginInterpreter = new loginEP.LoginInterpreter(tokensStorage);**

Comment: sí, con prefix también se puede, pero no lo veo necesario en este caso a menos que tengas clases con el mismo nombre en diferentes archivos